# Spark SQL - Join Two Tables on STRING and BIGINT using CAST

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a HIVE query that joins two tables using a value that is declared as String in one table and BIGINT in another table. The actual data is the same in both String and BIGINT.

This query runs fine in HIVE

```
SELECT TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
     ON TABLE1.<STRING COLUMN> = cast(TABLE2.<BIGINT COLUMN> as string)
```

But when I run the same query in spark-shell using HIVE context, I get a class cast exception.

```
hiveContext.sql("""SELECT TABLE1.*
FROM TABLE1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
     ON TABLE1.<STRING COLUMN> = cast(TABLE2.<BIGINT COLUMN> as string)""")
```

This results in:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's because of the `cast(bigint as string)`. It says `Text cannot be case to LongWritable`

Comment: But I don't get this error message if I remove the join clause.